# How to Handle Errors When Using Async with Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

New to Java Spring Boot. I have an API call that saves an entity to a SQL Database. The creation of the entity was taking way too long, so the method that actually saves the method was made asynchronous. Now the API returns a 201 right away instead of waiting for the object to be saved.

Old code:

```java
@PostMapping("/createStudent")
public ResponseEntity<Student> createStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {
    Student createdStudent = this.studentService.createStudent(student);
    return  createdStudent;
}
```

New Code:

```java
@PostMapping("/createStudent")
public ResponseEntity<Student> createStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {
    this.studentService.createAsyncStudent(student);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new Student(),HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

With the New Code, an error is occurring somewhere inside the createAsyncStudent method. But the API just returns a 200 right away. Is there a way to tell my React frontend that the API failed to create the student using the new code, or is it only possible with the old code?

There is error handling code in the createAsyncStudent method itself, but how do I return this error info to the frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you will need a mechanism (`polling`) to detect the creation progress of your entity. The simplest approach is to return a `202` status with creation ID for `createStudent` method, and the FE will periodically check the entity status of this ID via an endpoint (e.g: `GET /student-creation/{id}`). The backend will update its progress, including the created student ID as well as any error message into the `student-creation` table.
Another possible solution could be using a socket to maintain a connection and backend send the response of the error in a later time, but it's not as straightforward in the implementation as polling.